# Undefined variable error in function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't understand why I have the error

> NameError: name 'corpus' is not defined

```
def pretreatment(fileName):
    with open(fileName, 'r') as file:

        global corpus 

        text = file.readlines()

        corpus = []

        for occurrence in text:
            occurrence = occurrence.replace('.',' ')
            occurrence = occurrence.replace(',',' ')
            occurrence = occurrence.replace(';',' ')
            occurrence = occurrence.replace('(',' ')
            occurrence = occurrence.replace(')',' ')
            occurrence = occurrence.replace('?',' ')
            occurrence = occurrence.replace('!',' ')
            occurrence = occurrence.replace(':',' ')

            corpus.append(occurrence)

    return corpus

def lexical_analysis(corpus):
    global corpus

    lexical_corpus = pretreatment(corpus)

    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(lexical_corpus)

    return tokens

print(pretreatment("blabla.txt"))
print(lexical_analysis(corpus))
```

I have called the pretreatment function in the lexical_analysis function, but I still have an undefined variable error.

I would like to take advantage of and ask if there is a way to use the replace function in a more elegant way.

**EDIT:** Thank you for all the explanations. I just managed to declare the variables as global, I understood what the problem was and everything worked perfectly

> global variableName

Comment: `corpus` is a local variable name in `pretreatment`. Local variables are not shared; the name `corpus` in the global namespace is independent. You need to assign the returned value from the function to a global name.

Comment: [Read about how variables work and variable scope.](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

corpus is not defined in global scope, so you are getting error.

you can use like this,

```
 corpus = pretreatment("blabla.txt")

 print(lexical_analysis(corpus))
```

or

```
print(lexical_analysis(pretreatment("blabla.txt")))
```

Answer (score 2):

`corpus` is a local variable inside the function 'pretreatment`. Just because you have called the function doesn't mean it would (or should) begin to exist in the global scope. Try reading about scopes in [Python](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html).

```
print(lexical_analysis(pretreatment('blabla.txt')) # should work
```